# Principal curvatures of level hypersurface

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose we have a $C^2$ hypersurface $\Sigma$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Now let's consider level hypersurfaces
$$\Sigma_d=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}: d^{-1}(d(x))\}$$
where $d(x)$ is the distance function to the hypersurface $d(x,\Sigma)$, suppose we are taking very small distance $d$ or we are considering everything locally, now if we look at point $q$ in the level hypersurface $\Sigma_d$, there is a unique point $p\in \Sigma$ such that $d=d(p,q)=|q-p|$.

I want to compare the principal curvatures at these two points, suppose we have principal curvatures $\lambda_1\leq\lambda_2\leq\cdots\leq\lambda_n$ of $\Sigma$ at point $p$,

**Question(1)** what are principal curvatures of $\Sigma_d$ at point $q$ ? I mean can we write these principal curvatures $\tilde{\lambda}_i$ in terms of $\lambda_i$ and $d$ ?

**Question(2)**
If the ambient space is general manifold, is it same result as Question (1)

Any help is very much appreciated.

My work: When I use specific example: hemisphere, I realize there is probably a relation
$$\tilde{\lambda}_i=\frac{\lambda_i}{1-d\cdot\lambda_i}$$
Is this true for general hypersurface or in general manifold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding **Question(1)** your guess is correct!

Let $F(p)=p+d\cdot\nu(p)$ where $\nu$ is a locally defined  unit normal field on $\Sigma$. For small enough $d$ F will be an immersion, locally it's image is the parallel surface $\Sigma_d$ with unit normal field $\tilde\nu(F(p))=\nu(p)$.

By the chain rule
$$D_p\nu=D_p(\tilde\nu\circ F)=D_{F(p)}\tilde\nu\cdot D_pF=D_{F(p)}\tilde\nu\cdot(id+d\cdot D_p\nu)
$$

and hence $$\tilde S_{F(p)}=S_p\cdot(id-d\cdot S_p)^{-1}
$$

where $S$, $\tilde S$ are the corresponding shape operators.

By pure linear algebra if $v$  is an eigenvector of a $A$  with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and $p,q$ are polynomials such that $q(A)$ is invertible then $v$ is also an eigenvector of $p(A)\cdot q(A)^{-1}$ with eigenvalue $\frac{p(\lambda)}{q(\lambda)}$.

Thus  the principal curvatures $\tilde\lambda$ of $\Sigma_d$ which are the eigenvalues of $\tilde S_{F(p)}$ are given by
$\tilde{\lambda}_i=\frac{\lambda_i}{1-d\cdot\lambda_i}$.

Comment: I guess this idea doesn't work in general manifold setting.